# Disabling android hardware acceleration Runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have my application hardware accelerated for some devices but not for all. Mainly handsets running ICS. I know i can disable each view individually but i want to avoid that. 
So how can i disable Hardware Acceleration at runtime?

I want to do the opposite of that

```
getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
```

disabling it at window level.Not view level.

**Edit I did the opposite. I disabled HA at manifest and enable it at window level when needed.**
But the Q still stands

Comment: Which android version are u targeting? I read that starting from API Level 11 (correct me if i am wrong) you can disable/enable it application wide via the manifest. One thing I wonder about: On API Level < 11 is hardware acceleration by default enabled/disabled or enabled on supporting devices?

Answer (score 2):

[This Android blog article](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2011/03/android-30-hardware-acceleration.html) is a year old now (March, 2011), but it states: "Note that you currently cannot disable hardware acceleration at the window level."

Much of the article still seems valid - I'm currently chasing down a bug specific to the Galaxy Nexus that appears to stem from hardware acceleration and path clipping...